# Compare two strings ignoring little changes

Tags: c#, string, comparison

I want to compare two strings ignoring few words (say three).

Like if I compare these two strings:

```
"Hello! My name is Alex Jolig. Its nice to meet you."

"My name is Alex. Nice to meet you."
```

I should get result as `True`.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: This seems almost impossible without some significant work in a natural language parsing program...

Comment: its not possible by sentence. You can check one by one words.

Comment: Do you want to ignore words in both strings? For example what should happen if the second string is `Hi! My name is Alex. Nice to meet you.`

Comment: @defaultlocale No. just ignoring strings in one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing inbuilt that comes to my mind, but I think you can tokenise both the strings using a delimiter (' ' in your case) & punctuation marks (! & . in your case).

Once both the strings are broken down in ordered tokens you can apply a comparison between individual tokens as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the strings into words and compare them like this;

```
private bool compareStrings()
    {

        string stringLeft = "Hello! My name is Alex Jolig. Its nice to meet you.";
        string stringRight = "My name is Alex. Nice to meet you.";

        List<string> liLeft = stringLeft.Split(' ').ToList();
        List<string> liRight = stringRight.Split(' ').ToList();

        double totalWordCount = liLeft.Count();
        double matchingWordCount = 0;
        foreach (var item in liLeft)
        {
            if(liRight.Contains(item)){
                matchingWordCount ++;
            }
        }

        //return bool based on percentage of matching words
        return ((matchingWordCount / totalWordCount) * 100) >= 50;

    }
```

This returns a boolean based on a percentage of matching words, you might want to use a Regex or similar to replace some format characters for more accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on Fuzzy String Matching with Edit Distance in codeproject
You can probably extend this idea to suit your requirement. It uses Levenshtein's Edit Distance as a Fuzzy String Match.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162790/Fuzzy-String-Matching-with-Edit-Distance

Answer (score 0):

Hey so my here is my go at an answer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var string1 = "Hi thar im a string";
            var string2 = "Hi thar im a string";
            var string3 = "Hi thar im a similar string";
            var string4 = "im a really different string";
            var string5 = "Hi thar im a string but have many different words";

            Console.WriteLine(StringComparo(string1, string2));
            Console.WriteLine(StringComparo(string1, string3));
            Console.WriteLine(StringComparo(string1, string4));
            Console.WriteLine(StringComparo(string1, string5));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static bool StringComparo(string str1, string str2, int diffCounterLimiter = 3)
        {
            var counter = 0;
            var arr1 = str1.Split(' ');
            var arr2 = str2.Split(' ');

            while (counter <= diffCounterLimiter)
            {
                TreeNode bestResult = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < arr2.Length; j++)
                    {
                        var result = new TreeNode() { arr1Index = i, arr2Index = j };
                        if (string.Equals(arr1[i], arr2[j]) && (bestResult == null || bestResult.diff < result.diff))
                        {
                            bestResult = result;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // no result found
                if(bestResult == null)
                {
                    // any left over words plus current counter
                    return arr1.Length + arr2.Length + counter <= diffCounterLimiter;
                }

                counter += bestResult.diff;
                arr1 = arr1.Where((val, idx) => idx != bestResult.arr1Index).ToArray();
                arr2 = arr2.Where((val, idx) => idx != bestResult.arr2Index).ToArray();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class TreeNode
    {
        public int arr1Index;
        public int arr2Index;
        public int diff => Math.Abs(arr1Index - arr2Index);
    }
}
```

I tried to implement a tree search(I know its not really a search tree I may re write it a bit).

In essence it find the closest matched elements in each string.While under the limit of 3 differences it removes the elements matched them adds the difference and repeats. Hope it helps.